# How can i authenticate any user for login with an extra field (other then username/ email and password) in django

Tags: python, django, django-authentication

I am creating a user profile using django’s authentication system (from django.contrib.auth.models import User). Before this I am trying to extend the field of user using an extra field (i.e- userprofile= ceo/developer/marketinghead) in models.py. Here is my models.py file

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
# Create your models here.

class extendeduser(models.Model):
    userprofile_choice=(
        ('ceo', 'ceo'),
        ('developer', 'developer'),
        ('marketinghead', 'marketinghead'),
    )
    userprofile=models.CharField(choices= userprofile_choice, max_length=255, blank=False)
    user=models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.userprofile
```

now I am sucessfully registering the new user. Now I have created differrent html pages based on their profile. So at the time of login I take an extra input from user which is userprofile. And based on this I have created views.py for redirecting the user at correct place. Here is my views.py file :-

```
def login(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    uf = request.POST['userprofile']

    user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    user_profile = extendeduser.objects.filter(user = user)

    # print(user_profile[0])
    # print(uf)
    # print(user.get_username)
    # print(user.__dict__)
    #print(user.get_userprofile)

    if user is not None:
        if uf==user_profile[0]:
            if uf=='ceo':
                auth.login(request, user)
                messages.success(request, "You are logged-In")
                return redirect('wtoday')
            elif uf=='developer':
                auth.login(request, user)
                messages.success(request, "You are logged-In")
                return redirect('swhome')
            elif uf=='marketinghead':
                auth.login(request, user)
                messages.success(request, "You are logged-In")
                return redirect('sswhome')
            else:
                messages.warning(request, 'Invalid Credentials!!')
                return redirect('login')
        else:
            messages.warning(request, 'Invalid Credentials!')
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        messages.warning(request, 'Invalid Credentials')
        return redirect('login')
return render(request, 'accounts/login.html')
```

Everything is fine but this "if uf==user_profile[0]:" line of code is not working. basically it is checking that the "userprofile" field of any particular user which is store in database is same as at the time of login or not. I am saying this line of code is not working because when i comment that line and then without checking user profile from the databae i just redirecting them based on the data which he fiels at the time of login then it works. But I didn't want this.

Please help me out!!

Answer (score 1):

You can't compare `uf` and `userprofile[0]`, because `uf` is a string and `userprofile[0]` is an `extendeduser` object. Maybe `if uf == str(userprofile[0]):` is what you want.

Comment: yes, exactly what I wanted.. It works perfectly. Thank you so much @Allen Shaw.